# ERROR: ld.so: object 'getpid.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored

Tags: c, linux, dynamic, x86-64

When I try to use LD_PRELOAD as following,

```
LD_PRELOAD=getpid.so ./testpid
```

I get the following error...

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'getpid.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

I compile getpid.so by using

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o getpid.so getpid.c
```

and it contains the following code...

```
// getpid.c
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pid_t getpid(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return syscall(SYS_getpid);
}
```

`tespid.c` constains code which uses getpid as shown below and which is compiled by doing

```
gcc testpid -o testpid.c
```

What can be the problem here? Why is LD_PRELOAD not working?

```
// testpid.c
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "pid = %d!\n", getpid() );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like the loader is unable to find `getpid.so` as you've not mentioned the path to the library.

Try:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/full/path/to/getpid.so ./testpid
```

Comment: Very true! Instead of LD_PRELOAD=getpid.so ./testpid, it should be LD_PRELOAD=./getpid.so ./testpid. Now its working.

Comment: in my case I had to also set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and get 64-bit version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing error as below

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded
```

Below were my steps resolved the error for me.

Go to the path `/usr/lib64` and look for the libjemalloc using below commands*

```
  #cd /usr/lib64
  #ls | grep libjemalloc
```

if you don't find you don't have that package installed in your system

```
  $sudo yum whatprovides libjemalloc*
  $sudo yum install jemalloc-3.6.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
```