# Qustion about %env LD_PRELOAD=/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

**Hello friends! I hope you are well. I have a question about the code below used in Google Colaboratory to improve RAM usage (in this specific case it is to improve Stable Diffusion performance in A1111 webui).**

```
url = https://huggingface.co/mordecaaiiaart/ositoMalvado/resolve/main/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
%env TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=1
%env LD_PRELOAD=/content/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 #url downloaded file
```

**In Google Colaboratory it works well and does not give errors, but when using it in SageMaker (from Jupyter notebook) it gives me the following errors:**

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

**Does anyone have a version of libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 for my case? Or some possible solution. Thanks in advance!**

I'm trying to make libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 work on SageMaker GPU.

Comment: Not a Sagemaker expert - have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759189/error-ld-so-object-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libtcmalloc-minimal-so-4-3-0-fr), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723666/error-ld-so-object-ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded-ignored) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473941/error-ld-so-object-getpid-so-from-ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded-ignored)?

Comment: What is the instance you are using, are you on SageMaker Studio or Classic Notebook Instances?